# Modify HTMLCanvasElement after AppendChild (Angular)?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, html2canvas

I am hopeful you guys can help me out here, thanks ahead of time!

THE CONTEXT:
I'm building an email template UI.  The user gives their template a name and types (or copies) HTML into a textarea, and then when they click save that template is added to a firestore document.  On keyup, I'm using DomSanitizer to render the template below entry. All of those tasks are well in-hand.

THE TASK:
When the user clicks to save their template, I don't want to just save their template. A modal pops up with a preview of their HTML, scaled down to fit within the modal, and they have to click "save" a second time.  To do that, I need to be able to scale down the HTML.  Best as I can tell, in order to do THAT I need to convert it to an image. I'm using html2canvas to do that from the rendered HTML.

THE CHALLENGE:
So far I've only found `appendChild` as a method of rendering the html2canvas, but I can't seem to resize the canvas or the div after inserting it into the modal. It just slaps on there full-size. I need to have the image fit in the modal, preferably centered, preferably scaled to fit. Can you guys help?

THE CODE:

HTML:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 50%;">
    <h5 class="card-header">Create a Template:</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="templateName">Template Name:</label>
            <input name="templateName" 
                id="templateName" 
                rows="4"
                cols="30"
                class="form-control card-text" 
                [(ngModel)]="newTemplateName">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="newTemplateBody">Template Body:</label>
            <textarea name="newTemplateBody" 
                id="newTemplateBody" 
                rows="3" 
                placeholder="Enter your new template HTML here"
                class="form-control card-text"
                [(ngModel)]="newTemplateBody"
                (keyup)="sendHTML()">
            </textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="open(content)">
            Save Template
          </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div [innerHTML]="renderedHTML" id="renderedHTML"></div>

<!-- Button trigger modal. -->
  <ng-template #content let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Template Preview</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Are you sure you want to save?</p>
      <div id="previewDiv">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Save Template</button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

TypeScript:

```
//runs on every keyup
  sendHTML() {
    this.renderedHTML = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.newTemplateBody);
    
    let element = document.getElementById("renderedHTML");
    html2canvas(element, {
      allowTaint: true //allowTaint just lets me use external images in the html2canvas.
    }).then(canvas => {

      //the canvas is stored instead of rendered as we don't need it until the modal pops up.
      this.testImage = canvas;
    })
  }
  //opens the modal
  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title' })
    
    //attaches the image to the modal. This is where I have some issues.
    document.getElementById('previewDiv').append(this.testImage);
  }
```

THE VISUAL:
[image: This is what the modal looks like.]

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I have not solved this particular solution, but I did find a workaround. I just changed the size of the modal to accommodate the template's HTML.  I don't like having to scroll down, but it'll do for now.

It took longer than it should have to find how to resize the modal, so for anyone else with this issue it's just

```
open(content) {
  this.modalService.open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title', size: 'xl' })
}
```

Maybe I need to convert to a png instead of using a canvas? Hoping for input before I have to circle back around to this part.